# running jupyter + Apache Toree 0.2.0 with spark 2.2 kernel generate error (Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror')

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

Trying to run Apache Toree 0.2.0 on Jupyter Notebook with spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11 Generate the following error [Windows 10]:

```
(C:\Users\ale3s\Anaconda3) C:\Users\ale3s>jupyter notebook
[I 23:20:13.777 NotebookApp] sparkmagic extension enabled!
[I 23:20:13.874 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\ale3s
[I 23:20:13.874 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 23:20:13.876 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=2d7f006ac5f5a7d47f814f2bc13d3e84b3377847dfe575d6
[I 23:20:13.877 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:20:13.896 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=2d7f006ac5f5a7d47f814f2bc13d3e84b3377847dfe575d6
[I 23:20:14.132 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 23:20:31.557 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
"Starting Spark Kernel with SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\ale3s\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
C:\Users\ale3s\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit  --class org.apache.toree.Main "C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\apache_toree_scala\lib\toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar"  --profile C:\Users\ale3s\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-7d0fc349-bf0d-4dec-ab97-8b5236518654.json
[I 23:20:33.354 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 7d0fc349-bf0d-4dec-ab97-8b5236518654
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
(Scala,org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter@62679465)
(PySpark,org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.pyspark.PySparkInterpreter@6a988392)
(SparkR,org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.sparkr.SparkRInterpreter@1d71006f)
(SQL,org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.sql.SqlInterpreter@5b6813df)
17/09/30 23:20:37 WARN Main$$anon$1: No external magics provided to PluginManager!
17/09/30 23:20:39 WARN StandardComponentInitialization$$anon$1: Locked to Scala interpreter with SparkIMain until decoupled!
17/09/30 23:20:39 WARN StandardComponentInitialization$$anon$1: Unable to control initialization of REPL class server!
17/09/30 23:20:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[init] error: error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror', required by C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)

Failed to initialize compiler: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Failed to initialize compiler: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.exitingPhase(SymbolTable.scala:256)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20$lzycompute(IMain.scala:896)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20(IMain.scala:895)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble$lzycompute(IMain.scala:895)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble(IMain.scala:895)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.preamble(IMain.scala:918)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1337)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.stringFromWriter(package.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$class.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.apply(IMain.scala:908)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile$lzycompute(IMain.scala:1002)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile(IMain.scala:997)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compile(IMain.scala:579)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreterSpecific$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ScalaInterpreterSpecific.scala:295)
        at org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreterSpecific$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ScalaInterpreterSpecific.scala:289)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreterSpecific$class.start(ScalaInterpreterSpecific.scala:289)
[W 23:20:43.383 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 7d0fc349-bf0d-4dec-ab97-8b5236518654
        at org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter.start(ScalaInterpreter.scala:44)
        at org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter.init(ScalaInterpreter.scala:87)
        at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.InterpreterManager$$anonfun$initializeInterpreters$1.apply(InterpreterManager.scala:35)
        at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.InterpreterManager$$anonfun$initializeInterpreters$1.apply(InterpreterManager.scala:34)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
        at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.InterpreterManager.initializeInterpreters(InterpreterManager.scala:34)
        at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.StandardComponentInitialization$class.initializeComponents(ComponentInitialization.scala:90)
        at org.apache.toree.Main$$anon$1.initializeComponents(Main.scala:35)
        at org.apache.toree.boot.KernelBootstrap.initialize(KernelBootstrap.scala:101)
        at org.apache.toree.Main$.delayedEndpoint$org$apache$toree$Main$1(Main.scala:40)
        at org.apache.toree.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:24)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at org.apache.toree.Main$.main(Main.scala:24)
        at org.apache.toree.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/09/30 23:20:43 WARN Shell: Parent header is null for message C7B89F2771FB4175A5E6FAE9FF80648E of type comm_info_request
17/09/30 23:20:43 WARN Shell: Parent header is null for message BABC29AFE89A42838812F07446E26CDE of type comm_open
17/09/30 23:20:43 WARN Shell: Parent header is null for message 4A909AC3F2324F4F82A0E91F0E437C02 of type comm_open
```

Not sure what the problem exactly. Tried to add "settings.usejavacp.value = true" to ScalaInterpreter.scala, didn't work. The following is my run.bat file:

```
@REM
@REM     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
@REM
@REM Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
@REM distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
@REM WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
@REM See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
@REM limitations under the License
@REM
@echo off
setlocal

SET parent=%~dp0
FOR %%a IN ("%parent:~0,-1%") DO SET PROG_HOME=%%~dpa

IF "%SPARK_HOME%" == "" GOTO endprog
ECHO "Starting Spark Kernel with SPARK_HOME=%SPARK_HOME%"

FOR %%F IN (%PROG_HOME%lib\toree-assembly-*.jar) DO (
 SET TOREE_ASSEMBLY=%%F
 GOTO tests
)

:tests
    @REM disable randomized hash for string in Python 3.3+
    @REM SET TOREE_ASSEMBLY=%TOREE_ASSEMBLY:\=\\%
    SET PYTHONHASHSEED=0

IF "%SPARK_OPTS%" == "" GOTO toreeopts
SET SPARK_OPTS=%__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__%

:toreeopts
    IF "%TOREE_OPTS%" == "" GOTO runspark
    SET TOREE_OPTS=%__TOREE_OPTS__%

:runspark
    ECHO %SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit %SPARK_OPTS% --class org.apache.toree.Main "%TOREE_ASSEMBLY%" %TOREE_OPTS% %*
    %SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit %SPARK_OPTS% --class org.apache.toree.Main %TOREE_ASSEMBLY% %TOREE_OPTS% %*
    GOTO :eof

:endprog
    echo "SPARK_HOME must be set to the location of a Spark distribution!"
GOTO :eof
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm new to all these stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I installed docker and downloaded a stack that has everything I need and more from here: 
https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/all-spark-notebook/